# $this->db->get() with order by not working Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with CodeIgniter, Right now I am using following query for getting "banner" data but now I want to
fetch with "ORDER BY", how can I do this ?
My existing code is this

```
$data['banner'] = $this->db->get("banner")->result();
```

And I tried with following code, Where I am wrong ?

```
$data['banner'] = $this->db->get("banner")->order_by('status',"DESC")->result();
```

Comment: it should work.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra:  giving me error "Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::order_by()"

Answer (score 1):

Change it to as :

```
$this->db->order_by('status', 'desc');
$data = $this->db->get('banner')->result();
```